# How to observe some property of ViewModel from View (UWP)

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

My View need to do something such as animate multiple controls in View page after a viewModel property changed. How to observe ViewModel property from my View?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you do this by raising the `PropertyChanged` event of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface when you set a property.

Any bindings that use the property should receive the event and update their target property.

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that for everything to work the `UpdateSourceTrigger` in the binding needs to be set to `PropertyChanged`. It is by default for most of the controls, but not always.

Comment: @BartłomiejPopielarz That is a common misconception. You only need to set UpdateSourceTrigger for Bindings that are supposed to update their source property when the target property changes, like the Text property of a TextBox. UpdateSourceTrigger has no effect on OneWay Bindings (i.e. the view model to view direction).